# R - Data frame containing an array of comma separated values

Tags: arrays, r

I have data frame, with a horrible schema where many of the dimensions have values which are comma seperated arrays - instead of these arrays, i wish to apply operations to values like count, sum, mean etc

```
e.g. 
    colA ColB
    A [0.0,0.0,0.0,2177.0068,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
    B [0.0,0.0,650.2635,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
    C [0.0,0.0,406.3296,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
    D \N
    E [0.0,0.0,982.2527,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
    F [0.0,0.0,0.0,163.6882,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
```

Does anyone have an elegant way of summing/counting/mean of each array?

Thanks

Comment: can you post in your question the dput of your data ? (`dput(df)`), and the output you'd like to get ?

Answer (score 0):

Convert this to long form in which case it is easy to perform aggregations.

**1)** Assuming `DF` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end remove the square brackets in `ColB` and separate `ColB` into rows converting appropriately.  Then group by `colA` and take the sum and mean of `ColB` (and possibly use other aggregation functions as well).  If you don't want an NA for D filter out the rows for which ColB does not start with [.  See the `filter` statement in (2).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF %>%
   mutate(ColB = gsub("[][]", "", ColB)) %>%
   separate_rows(ColB, sep = "[^-0-9.]", convert = TRUE) %>%
   group_by(ColA) %>%
   summarize(Sum = sum(ColB), Mean = mean(ColB)) %>%
   ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  ColA    Sum  Mean
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A     2177. 218. 
2 B      650.  65.0
3 C      406.  40.6
4 D       NA   NA  
5 E      982.  98.2
6 F      164.  16.4
```

**2)** Alternately use the fact that the ColB strings that start with [ are JSON.  In this case we filtered out the non-JSON elements of `colB` first.

```
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyr)

DF %>%
   filter(substring(ColB, 1, 1) == "[") %>%
   rowwise() %>%
   mutate(ColB = list(fromJSON(ColB))) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   unnest %>%
   group_by(ColA) %>%
   summarize(Sum = sum(ColB), Mean = mean(ColB)) %>%
   ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  ColA    Sum  Mean
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A     2177. 218. 
2 B      650.  65.0
3 C      406.  40.6
4 E      982.  98.2
5 F      164.  16.4
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "ColA ColB
    A [0.0,0.0,0.0,2177.0068,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
    B [0.0,0.0,650.2635,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
    C [0.0,0.0,406.3296,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
    D \\N
    E [0.0,0.0,982.2527,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
    F [0.0,0.0,0.0,163.6882,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```